# A 'UX Manifesto' based on the Agile Manifesto

Tags: lean-ux, agile, manifesto

Based on a [previous question](https://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/40059/is-the-agile-manifesto-based-on-ux-philosophies-or-vice-versa) I asked, and also just reading a few articles lamenting the way [Agile software development should be killed off](https://web.archive.org/web/20160811124734/http://pragdave.me:80/blog/2014/03/04/time-to-kill-agile/) and [the teaching and learning of UX design appears to be 'broken'](https://medium.com/@danmaccarone/the-ux-of-learning-ux-is-broken-f972b27d3273?), I think it is important to get back to the true problem that the philosophy/approach originally intended to be achieve by the Agile Manifesto and understand how it might also apply to address some of the 'excesses' introduced by the whole UX field:

> We are uncovering better ways of developing software by doing it and
> helping others do it. Through this work we have come to value:
>
> - Individuals and interactions over processes and tools
> - Working software over comprehensive documentation
> - Customer collaboration over    contract negotiation
> - Responding to change over following a plan
>
> That is, while there is value in the items on the right, we value the
> items on the left more.

So in the same way, is it not possible to also adapt this to UX design to say something like:

We are uncovering better ways of designing
products/services by being more empathetic and helping others do it.
Through this work we have come to value:

- Users needs and wants over business processes and UX tools
- Solving real problems over comprehensive assets and deliverable
- Stakeholder collaboration over requirements negotiation
- Understanding the intangible over refining the measurable

That is, while there is value in the items on
the right, we value the items on the left more.

Does it not also capture the essence of Agile and Lean methodologies as well? Did we miss out on having that moment of clarity that the people who conceived the Agile philosophy had?

Answer (score 7):

Well there is the [Lean UX Manifesto](https://www.smashingmagazine.com/2014/01/lean-ux-manifesto-principle-driven-design/) from Anthony Viviano, Ajay Revels and Ha Phan:

> - Early customer validation over releasing products with unknown    end-user value
> - Collaborative design over designing on an island
> - Solving user problems over designing the next “cool” feature
> - Measuring KPIs over undefined success metrics
> - Applying appropriate tools over following a rigid plan
> - Nimble design over heavy wireframes, comps or specs
>
> As stated in the Agile Manifesto, “While there is value in the items
>   on the right, we value the items on the left more.”